# Converting CSV data to a Dataset

Tags: import, dataset, labeling

I have data in a csv file. The first row has labels, and the first column, too.

```
Datos = Import["C:\\Users\\jodom\\Desktop\\Data.csv"]
```

Tha data in the csv file is that:

```
{{"No", "Vol", "Vel"}, {1, 500, 45}, {2, 700, 67}, {3, 350, 87}, {4, 
123, 23}, {5, 587, 45}, {6, 435, 89}, {7, 896, 65}, {8, 125, 
45}, {9, 476, 27}, {10, 987, 80}}
```

I put those csv data into a dataset:

```
B = Dataset[Datos]
```

You can check it out as an image here,on how it has seen on wolfram after the import:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B56r_V66BiodQUhUMWNHcHZFOWc/view?usp=sharing

Now I want to convert the first row that has the labels, into a head or label of the dataset, and the first column into a label column, so I can get data from this dataset, like

```
Dataset[labelrow, labelcolumn]
```

Comment: can you post your image here instead rather than a google drive link. And maybe reduce the size of the dataset and paste it in the question as well. Right now your post is not very helpful for the reader.

Comment: for any reason, the mathematica.stackexchange.com webbpage dont let me paste an image....
The dataset is very short...

Comment: see if the image format is a .PNG which should work. There is a picture tab close to where you wrote the question which should ask you for a picture input

Comment: why don't you make up an example with 3/4 rows and columns and just post as text.

Comment: No man, still, im having the same error to upload the image "imurg failed to process your recuest". I changed the format to png, jpg. It does not working.

Comment: But, can't you open the link ?

Comment: @jodomofo No we can't, because it requires permission to access. You should change the sharing permissions on the file, or generate a new link.

Comment: You should delete this question because you have posted a new version of it. We don't want to have the question posted twice.

Comment: I have already change the privileges, so you can see it now

Comment: I have posted a similiar question to a diferent problem, not a new vertion of it.

Comment: @jodomofo please delete the other question that you posted. it seems the same thing

Comment: Here, the data has labels, so i wanna convert that labels into a dataset labels

Answer (score 7):

As of 11.2, I would suggest doing either:

`Import["test.csv", "Dataset", "HeaderLines" -> 1]`

or

`Import["test.csv", "Dataset", "HeaderLines" -> {1, 1}]`

[image]

Comment: Mathematica can't always correctly infer the import format so `Import[test.csv, {"CSV","Dataset"}]` is a safer option.

Comment: If the extension .csv is given, it should be able to infer the format.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{"No", "Vol", "Vel"}, {1, 500, 45}, {2, 700, 67}, {3, 350, 
87}, {4, 123, 23}, {5, 587, 45}, {6, 435, 89}, {7, 896, 65}, {8, 125, 45},
{9, 476, 27}, {10, 987, 80}}


dataset = Dataset[Association@MapThread[(#1 -> <|"Vol" -> #2, "Vel" -> #3 |> &), 
Transpose@Rest@data]]


dataset[1, "Vol"]
(* 500 *)

dataset[1,"Vel"]

(* 45 *)
```

Comment: @jodomofo please see this answer

Comment: @jodomofo i dont understand what you mean? The answer I posted is clearly a Dataset and you can get the value by row and by column. I dont understand what else you require?

Comment: yes it is, but it has to look like a table, 'cause it will use in an inform. And, after this, i wil have to operate with each colum...

Check what a do in the answer that i published...

it has to look like this, and funcion like a dataset.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B56r_V66BiodU0lDblRnaHFiZjg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @jodomofo can you check my code again. Run it. it will look like a table now

Comment: THAT IS MAN !
THANKS !.....

Now, could you check the another  question that i posted. Are similar, but not the same, and i wanna the same resutls

Comment: I think @kglr has probably addressed that question already.

Comment: Thanks Man, that is it ! Thanks a lot....I Really Apreciate it

Comment: One quesion !...i wanna operate the two columns into a new one. Its like :

Den = Vol / Vel

I mean... create a new colum that operate with two columns, a column name Den that it is the soved of Col Vol divided into Col Vel....

Or i have to create anther post for it ?

Answer (score 3):

As the OP,you have a `.csv` file like:

[image]

Then you just use `SemanticImport`

```
SemanticImport["Data.csv"]
```

[image]

---

Of course,if you have a `data` like:

```
data = {{"No", "Vol", "Vel"}, {1, 500, 45}, {2, 700, 67}, {3, 350, 
   87}, {4, 123, 23}, {5, 587, 45}, {6, 435, 89}, {7, 896, 65}, {8, 
   125, 45}, {9, 476, 27}, {10, 987, 80}}
```

You can get a `Dataset`

```
SemanticImportString[ExportString[data, "CSV"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
datos =  {{"No", "Vol", "Vel"}, {1, 500, 45}, {2, 700, 67}, {3, 350, 87},
          {4, 123, 23}, {5, 587, 45}, {6, 435, 89}, {7, 896, 65}, {8, 125, 5},
          {9, 476, 27}, {10, 987, 80}};

ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[datos[[2;;,1]]->  
      (AssociationThread[Rest@First@datos->Rest[#]]&/@Rest[datos])]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ds[2, "Vel"]
```

> 67

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is this:

```
association = AssociationThread[ First @ data, ## ]& /@ data; (* data = Datos *)

dataset = Association /* Dataset @@ (
    association // Query[ All, Lookup[##, "No"] -> Part[##, 2 ;; 3] & ]
)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then

```
dataset[ 2, "Vol" ]
```

> 700

Comment: While you can do this in one step, I find doing it sequentially easier to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

I have already do something....

```
data1 = {{"No", "Vol", "Vel"}, {1, 500, 45}, {2, 700, 67}, {3, 350, 87}, {4, 123, 23}, {5, 587, 45}, {6, 435, 89}, {7, 896, 65}, {8, 125, 45}, {9, 476, 27}, {10, 987, 80}} 

data2 = Drop[data1, 1] 
data3 = Dataset[data2] 
data4 = data3[All, <|"No" -> 1, "Vol" -> 2, "Vel" -> 3|>]
```

But if you see, i have to delete the first row, to create the labels....there is a way to do that without deleting the first row? another thing....can i do the samething with the rows>