# Labeling dataset

Tags: labeling

I have data in a csv file. The first row has labels, and the first column, too.

```
Datos = Import["C:\\Users\\jodom\\Desktop\\Data.csv"]
```

Tha data in the csv file is that:

```
{{6, 500, 45}, {7, 700, 67}, {1, 350, 87}, {4,123, 23}, {9, 587, 45}, {6, 435, 89}, {7, 896, 65}, {8, 125, 
45}, {4, 476, 27}, {15, 987, 80}}
```

I put those csv data into a dataset:

```
B = Dataset[Datos]
```

You can check it out as an image here,on how it has to be seen on wolfram after the import:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B56r_V66BiodYU5nYmJpNUtGZ3c/view?usp=sharing

Now i wanna add a fisrt row that has labels, into a head or label of the dataset, and then a first colum, with labels too, so i can get data from this dataset, like dataset[labelrow, labelcolumn].

Comment: We still can't access the link to your file. It requires permission to access. You should change the sharing permissions on the file, or generate a new link.

Comment: I have already change the privileges,so you can see it now

Comment: jodomofo, Welcome to mma.se. We suggest 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs!](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking [the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t).

Comment: I am voting to close this as it is pretty much the exact duplicate of [(138866)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138866/764). This question is much unclearer than the one linked and the answers there can be trivially adapted to this question.

Answer (score 2):

```
datos={{6, 500, 45}, {7, 700, 67}, {1, 350, 87}, {4,123, 23}, {9, 587, 45}, 
       {6, 435, 89}, {7, 896, 65}, {8, 125, 5}, {4, 476, 27}, {15, 987, 0}};

rowkeys=CharacterRange["A","Z"][[;;10]];
colkeys={"X","Y","Z"};

ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[rowkeys->(AssociationThread[colkeys->#]&/@datos)]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ds["D","Y"]
```

> 123

Comment: i think he has posted the same question before.

Comment: @Ali, i may be wrong, but the two questions are slightly different; this one asking to add both row labels and column labels. In the other question, the row and column labels are part of the input data.

Comment: i see. We can ask him to merge the two questions and have sub-parts rather than having two separate ones

Comment: That is what i want to know...THANKS AGAING!