# Convert dataset to {row_head, col_head, value} list

Tags: dataset

I have a dataset imported using [this method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/173732/34223) with both row and column head are some numeric values shown below.

[image: sample data]

Now I would like to convert the following dataset to a list of {row_head, col_head, value} points for the future plotting.

[image: target list]

Currently, I use the following to convert (inspired by [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56744/34223)). I wonder is there any other way to do this. Thank you!

```
x = data[All, List @@@ Normal@Normal@# &];
y = Normal@Normal@x;
z = Function[{t}, Join[{t[[1]]}, #] & /@ t[[2]]] /@ y;
w = ToExpression@Flatten[z,1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you'll see two solutions but remember there is always a better way:

### MapIndexed

`MapIndexed` passes positions of elements as arguments. It also works with `Dataset` and `Key`:

```
MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ #2[[All, 1]], #1} &, data, {2}]
```

The output is a `Dataset`, so for conversation use:

```
Normal[MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ #2[[All, 1]], #1} &, data, {2}][Values, Values]]
```

### ReplacePart

With `ReplacePart` you can use patterns for positions:

```
ReplacePart[data, {a_, b_} :> {Keys[data][[a]], Keys[data[[b]]][[b]], data[[a, b]]}]
```

Since `a` and `b` are integers like 1,2 instead of `Key`, `Keys[data][[...]]` was used.
The output is a `Dataset`, so for conversation use:

```
Normal[ReplacePart[
   data, {a_, b_} :> {Keys[data][[a]], Keys[data[[b]]][[b]], 
     data[[a, b]]}][Values, Values]]
```

> Note: The speed of `MapIndexed` is much faster compare to `ReplacePart`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Both methods are very nice, particularly the 1st when I tried on a dataset of over 1M pts.